# Is this a case to use liftM?

Tags: haskell

I have the following function:

```
sendq :: Socket -> B.ByteString -> String -> IO PortNumber -> IO ()
sendq s datastring host port = do
     hostAddr <- inet_addr host
     sendAllTo s datastring (SockAddrInet port hostAddr)
```

whereas sendAllTo has the function signature

```
sendAllTo :: Socket -> ByteString -> SockAddr -> IO ()
```

The problem is the from previous functions I get handed down an IO PortNumber where SockAddr takes a PortNumber only. I tried to make these two compatible by promoting sendAllTo into the IO monad:

```
liftM sendAllTo s datastring (SockAddrInet port hostAddr)
```

but no joy. Tells me something about to many arguments. Is this a case for liftM? How do I apply it correctly?

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a particular reason why `sendq` takes an `IO PortNumber` rather than a `PortNumber`?

Comment: @valderman The library function that extracts the port number from a socket returns an IO PortNumber: `socketPort s -> IO PortNumber`. A previous function takes a socket and extracts the port.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`liftM` and friends serve the purpose of jacking up *pure* functions to a monadic setting, much as the `Applicative` combinators do.

```
liftM :: Monad m => (s -> t) -> m s -> m t
```

There are two issues with the code you tried. One is just a lack of parentheses.

```
liftM sendAllTo :: IO Socket -> IO (ByteString -> SockAddr -> IO ())
```

which is not what you meant. The other issue is that

```
sendAllTo :: Socket -> ByteString -> SockAddr -> IO ()
```

is a *monadic* operation, so lifting it will deliver two layers of `IO`. The usual method is to parenthesize the pure prefix of the application, like so

```
liftM (sendAllTo s datastring) :: IO SockAddr -> IO (IO ())
```

You can then build the argument with `liftM2`.

```
liftM2 SockAddrInet ioport (inet_adder host) :: IO SockAddr
```

That gives you

```
liftM (sendAllTo s datastring) (liftM2 SockAddrInet ioport (inet_adder host))
  :: IO (IO ())
```

which will achieve precisely nothing as it stands, because it explains how to compute an operation but doesn't actually invoke it! That's where you need

```
join (liftM (sendAllTo s datastring) (liftM2 SockAddrInet ioport (inet_addr host)))
  :: IO ()
```

or, more compactly

```
sendAllTo s datastring =<< liftM2 SockAddrInet ioport (inet_adder host)
```

**Plug.** The [Strathclyde Haskell Enhancement](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/she/) supports [idiom brackets](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/she/idiom.html), where

`(|f a1 .. an|) :: m t` if `f :: s1 -> ... -> sn -> t` and `a1 :: m s1` ... `an :: m sn`.

These do the same job for `Applicative m` as the `liftM` family do for monads, treating `f` as a pure n-ary function and `a1`..`an` as effectful arguments. `Monad`s can and should be `Applicative` too, so

```
(|SockAddrInet ioprot (inet_addr host)|) :: IO SockAddr
```

and

```
(|(sendAllTo s datastring) (|SockAddrInet ioprot (inet_addr host)|)|) :: IO (IO ())
```

The notation then allows you to invoke computed monadic computations like the above, with a postfixed `@`.

```
(|(sendAllTo s datastring) (|SockAddrInet ioprot (inet_addr host)|) @|) :: IO ()
```

Note that I'm still parenthesizing the pure prefix of the application, so that the `f` of the template is the whole of `(sendAllTo s datastring)`. The notation allows you to mark pure arguments in any position with a `~`, so you can write this

```
(|sendAllTo ~s ~datastring (|SockAddrInet ioprot (inet_addr host)|) @|) :: IO ()
```

if the mood takes you.

**Rant.** We spend far too much energy on figuring out the right `liftM`, `join`, `=<<`, `do`, `(|...~...@|)` punctuation in order to explain how to cut up a type as a value-explaining kernel (`()` here) in an effect-explaining context (`IO` here). If this up-cutting were made more explicitly in types, we should need less noise in our programs to slap values and computations into alignment. I should much prefer the computer to infer where the `~` and `@` marks go, but as things stand, Haskell types are too ambiguous a document to make that feasible.

Comment: Hmm looks like we came up with the same answer (minus the latter half of yours), but you have a lot more explanation to how you came up with it. +1

Comment: Yes. Basically, you write down the application structure you want, ignoring monads; then you look at what's pure and what's effectful and speckle on the appropriate lifting punctuation.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to extract the port number from the IO monad using `<-` like this

```
sendq s datastring host ioport = do
     hostAddr <- inet_addr host
     port     <- ioport
     sendAllTo s datastring (SockAddrInet port hostAddr)
```

Comment: @JFritsch, `liftM2 ((sendAllTo s datastring .) . SockAddrInet) ioport (inet_addr host)`.

Answer (score 3):

What about:

```
sendq s datastring host ioport = (SockAddrInet <$> inet_addr host <*> ioport)
     >>= sendAllTo s datastring
```

We use `liftM` (actually, I prefer `<$>` but they are the same thing) to construct the `SockAddrInet` and then use the standard `>>=`.

The key is to use the lifting on only the part of the expression that can be easily lifted, and then use other ways of dealing with monads to form the rest of the code. This gives concise and readable code.